# Combine alert pause and invisible in beamer

Tags: beamer, transparency

I would like to combine alert, pause and invisible in beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
    \begin{itemize}[<+|alert@+>]
        \item item A
        \item item B
        \item item C
        \item item D
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above code works but it shows all items. I would like to start with all items hidden, then shown when I reach the item and then their transparency reduced thereafter.

I have tried to use something like `[<+(1) |alert@+>| invisible@-+>]` but it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
    \begin{itemize}[<+|alert@+|invisible@1-+(-1)>]
        \item item A
        \item item B
        \item item C
        \item item D
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It works as expected